# In Sybase - Need to insert values from temp table after an execute(query with run time values)

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Code:

```
exec ('select @colname,count(*) as cnt into tmp_final from dbo.'+@tablename+' group by '+@colname+' having count(*) >1')
insert into log_table (order id,order key )
select order id,order key from tmp_final
```

When I give values at runtime only then the tmp_final table will be loaded post which the log table should be inserted with the data.

Comment: Please make the exact issue clearer so that the community can help

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere?) and version? if this is ASE I would expect the current code to to generate an error at compile time complaining that the `tmp_final` table does not exist; are you getting any errors and if so please post the complete error message(s)

Comment: Yes your right am working in IDERA Rapid sql tool sybase version 12.6.I am error at compile time that tmp_final doesnot exist

Answer (score 0):

The `exec(select/into tmp_final)` call is compiled at the point when the `exec()` is actually being executed.

Here's what happens at the time the SQL batch is submitted to ASE:

- user hits 'send' and SQL batch is submitted to ASE
- the `exec()` call is ignored during compilation phase (ie, the `tmp_final` table does not exist at this point)
- the `insert into` is compiled, but because the `tmp_final` table does not exist (yet) an error is generated (eg, 'table `tmp_final` does not exist')
- the SQL batch cannot be compiled (due to the error)
- the SQL batch cannot be run

To get around this error you have a few options:

1. submit the `exec()` and `insert into` in separate batches, ie, once the
   `exec()` has created the `tmp_final` **then** submit a new batch
   that includes the `insert into` command
2. wrap the `insert into` in its own `exec()` wrapper so that this command is compiled a) at run time and b) **after** the `tmp_final` table has been created (by the first `exec()` call)
3. create the `tmp_final` table at some earlier point in time and replace the `exec(select/into)` (compiled at run time) with a `insert/select` (compiled at submission time)